# how to resize image from url by clicking opaque button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, resize

I'm pretty new to objective and I'm trying to enhance an iPhone app (coding done by someone else). I'm trying to pull an image from the internet and its displayed as a thumbnail.

The idea is to have the user click the button (opaque with the image behind it) and have it resize to full size - covering the whole screen.

This is my .m file code for the button action:

```
-(IBAction)changeFullSize{

    test.text = @"YOU HAVE CLICKED!";
    // grab the original image

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [urlImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
}
```

I thought something like resizing would be easy but I just can't get it right for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem? I am assuming that the image is changing to an image of the donkey from shrek :P ?

Comment: The code you submitted doesn't display the newImage. Did you forget to display it or is that not working?

Comment: It's not working I think. It was: urlImage.image = newImage; 
Or is that not right?

Answer (score 1):

can't you just put your image into a UIImageView and set the content mode to  UIViewContentModeScaleToFill?  Then just resize the UIImageview to full screen when the button is tapped?

Comment: Yeps that's the idea. It would be helpful if you could paste a  small code snippet in? I'm still pretty new and I just can't get the syntax right :( Thanks for your help.

Comment: Finally got it to work, was just a simple 2 lines:
urlImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    urlImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);